# How Foundry interactive with other Contract Function and Log its Revert Message

Tags: foundry

I'm using Foundry to develop my contract. I want to calculate Uniswap V3 amount out. I find a Quoter Contract and call it in my Test Unit
The Quoter Contract Address: `https://etherscan.io/address/0xb27308f9f90d607463bb33ea1bebb41c27ce5ab6#code`

I call this contract's function

`quoteExactInput(bytes memory path, uint256 amountIn) external returns (uint256 amountOut);`

This Function will revert and return amount out in it's revert message.
How can I log this message? I want it's amount out.

Comment: Can you just do `forge test -vvvv` ? It displays the trace which should also log the values.